# using pandas apply lambda with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, apply

| Product | Price | Timestamp | AdjPrice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1142 | 1/3/2022 |  |
| A1 | 1148 | 1/4/2022 |  |
| A1 | 1177 | 1/5/2022 |  |
| A1 | 1163 | 1/6/2022 |  |
| A1 | 1160 | 1/7/2022 |  |

I have the above dataframe. The last column (AdjPrice) must be populated by multiplying the Price with a static factor (0.15 for instance), if the Timestamp is less than a given date (1/5/2022).

`mydate = pd.to_datetime("1/5/2022",format='%d/%m/%Y')`

`df['AdjPrice'] = df['AdjPrice'].apply(lambda x: (df['Price'] * 0.15) if x['Timestamp'] < mydate else df['Price']`

gives me the following error.

`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

I'm not sure how to achieve this. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will fix your problem:

```
mydate = pd.to_datetime("1/5/2022",format='%d/%m/%Y')
df['AdjPrice'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Price'] * 0.15 if pd.to_datetime(x['Timestamp']) < mydate else x['Price'], axis=1)
```

Comment: This helped clear up the way I understood the apply/lambda usage, and it works perfectly too. Thanks, Pedro.